# how to convert dash or any date format into slash datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string strDate = 16-08-1979   i.e dd-MM-yyyy

Datetime Dob=DateTime.Parse(strDate.ToString() , new CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

I want every format convert into "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: "I want every format convert into ..." what is preventing you from doin so? only the string representation has a format, the `DateTime` object has no format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example you provided, there's a few steps you'd need to take first.

1. Your `strDate` value isn't a data type, so make it a string.

   ```
   string strDate = "16-8-1979";
   ```
2. This is already a string that's in a bad format, but we can parse it to a DateTime value to work with.

   ```
   DateTime.TryParse(strDate, out DateTime myDate);
   ```
3. Now we've got a DateTime to work with, we can output a properly formatted string with the value.

   ```
   string output = myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // output should be 08/16/1979
   ```

Comment: 2 things; 1) If you're going to use `TryParse` don't ignore the result - otherwise you may as well just use `Parse` 2) It would be better to use `TryParseExact` as different locales will treat the same date differently using `TryParse` depending on the settings of the machine calling it.